# Creating a sliding image gallery that does not glitch on image change

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, jquery-animate

I have created a sliding image gallery and when the button is pushed it slides the picture across and updates the image attribute for the relevant sections. 
However this works perfectly like 50% of the time. The other times there is a second glitch and the images then go in place as expected.
I have attached the javascript methods for the animate method and the array change method. I have looked elsewhere and cannot see anyone else with a similar issue or where I am going wrong, especially when it doesn't happen often.

```
imageGallery.leftSelect.onclick = function () {
    window.setTimeout(imageGallery.rightClick, 250);
    imageGallery.animateImages('.image1', '.imageRight');
    imageGallery.animateImages('.imageRight', '.imageNoneRight');
    imageGallery.animateImages('.imageLeft', '.image1');
    imageGallery.animateImages('.imageNoneLeft', '.imageLeft');
};
```

---

```
animateImages: function (classFrom, classTo) {
    var classMoving = $(classFrom);
    var classGoingTo = $(classTo);

    classMoving.animate({
        top: classGoingTo.css('top'),
        left: classGoingTo.css('left'),
        width: classGoingTo.css('width'),
        opacity: classGoingTo.css('opacity'),
    }, 258, function () {
        console.log('Animated');
        classMoving.css({"width":'', "opacity":'', "top":'', "left":'', });
    });
},

rightClick: function () {
    imageGallery.imagesDisplay.push(imageGallery.imagesDisplay.shift());

    imageGallery.imageNoneLeft.setAttribute('src', imageGallery.imagesDisplay[2]);
    imageGallery.imageLeft.setAttribute('src', imageGallery.imagesDisplay[1]);
    imageGallery.imageMain.setAttribute('src', imageGallery.imagesDisplay[0]);
    imageGallery.imageRight.setAttribute('src', imageGallery.imagesDisplay[10]);
    imageGallery.imageNoneRight.setAttribute('src', imageGallery.imagesDisplay[9]);

},
```

Can someone assist, I really need this to work?

If there is anything not clear or you need more code let me know.

Thanks,

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80799/discussion-on-question-by-rmitchell-creating-a-sliding-image-gallery-that-does-n).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First things first, the culprit was the `setAttribute` of all images i.e. whatever you were doing inside the `rightClick` and `leftClick` functions were the reasons why you were seeing a *glitch*. Changing `src` of an `img` tag produces the *glitch*.

But then we cannot simply remove it because your approach relies heavily on this swapping of images.

I had to breakdown and really understand your approach first. The way it worked was that you would animate, for example, `image1` (the centered one) to move to the position of `imageLeft` upon click on the `rightCarousel` button. On that same click, you had a `setTimeout` of almost the duration of the animation to call `rightClick` function. This `rightClick` function then swaps the images so that `image1` can always remain at the center and only images can come and go after animation. This was the problem.

What I had to change was that all image tags i.e. `imageNoneLeft`, `imageLeft`, `image1`, `imageRight` & `imageNoneRight` would change each others classes such that their position remains changed after animations.

Also, I had to add another `animateImages` line inside your `leftSelect` and `rightSelect` callbacks to animate the furthest images i.e. `imageNoneLeft` & `imageNoneRight` to animate to each other's positions with respect to the click of the buttons.

Take a look at [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tahirahmed/97Lng59b/). It will help you understand a lot better. And let me know if you have any questions.

**JavaScript:**

```
var imageGallery={
    prefix:'https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/45891870/Experiments/StackOverflow/1.5/',
    imagesDisplay:['JS.jpg','PIXI.jpg','GSAP.jpg','JS.jpg','PIXI.jpg','GSAP.jpg','JS.jpg','PIXI.jpg','GSAP.jpg','JS.jpg','PIXI.jpg'],
    rightSelect:document.querySelector('.rightCarousel'),
    leftSelect:document.querySelector('.leftCarousel'),
    imageMain:document.querySelector('.image1'),
    imageLeft:document.querySelector('.imageLeft'),
    imageRight:document.querySelector('.imageRight'),
    imageNoneLeft:document.querySelector('.imageNoneLeft'),
    imageNoneRight:document.querySelector('.imageNoneRight'),
    init:function(){
        imageGallery.imagesDisplay.push(imageGallery.imagesDisplay.shift());
        imageGallery.imageNoneLeft.setAttribute('src',imageGallery.prefix+imageGallery.imagesDisplay[2]);
        imageGallery.imageLeft.setAttribute('src',imageGallery.prefix+imageGallery.imagesDisplay[1]);
        imageGallery.imageMain.setAttribute('src',imageGallery.prefix+imageGallery.imagesDisplay[0]);
        imageGallery.imageRight.setAttribute('src',imageGallery.prefix+imageGallery.imagesDisplay[10]);
        imageGallery.imageNoneRight.setAttribute('src',imageGallery.prefix+imageGallery.imagesDisplay[9]);
    },
    animateImages:function(classFrom,classTo){
        var classMoving=$(classFrom);
        var classGoingTo=$(classTo);
        classMoving.animate({
            top:classGoingTo.css('top'),
            left:classGoingTo.css('left'),
            width:classGoingTo.css('width'),
            opacity:classGoingTo.css('opacity')
        },258,function(){
            $(this).removeClass(classFrom.substr(1));
            $(this).addClass(classTo.substr(1));
            $(this).removeAttr('style');
        });
    }
};
imageGallery.init();
imageGallery.leftSelect.onclick=function(){
    imageGallery.animateImages('.imageNoneRight','.imageNoneLeft');
    imageGallery.animateImages('.imageRight','.imageNoneRight');
    imageGallery.animateImages('.image1','.imageRight');
    imageGallery.animateImages('.imageLeft','.image1');
    imageGallery.animateImages('.imageNoneLeft','.imageLeft');
};
imageGallery.rightSelect.onclick=function(){
    imageGallery.animateImages('.imageNoneLeft','.imageNoneRight');
    imageGallery.animateImages('.imageLeft','.imageNoneLeft');
    imageGallery.animateImages('.image1','.imageLeft');
    imageGallery.animateImages('.imageRight','.image1');
    imageGallery.animateImages('.imageNoneRight','.imageRight');
};
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80800/discussion-on-answer-by-tahir-ahmed-creating-a-sliding-image-gallery-that-does-n).